# nginx proxy_pass and rewrite for seafile proxy

Tags: mod-rewrite, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-location, seafile-server

I'm running a seafile vm (private network) behind a Plesk vm (public).

Right now I'm using apache as proxy but was wondering how to get this setup running with nginx only.

This works:

```
RewriteEngine On

ProxyPass /seafhttp http://192.168.10.102:8082
ProxyPassReverse /seafhttp http://192.168.10.102:8082
RewriteRule ^/seafhttp - [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://192.168.10.102:8000/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse  / http://192.168.10.102:8000/
```

This doesn't:

```
location /seafhttp {
    rewrite ^/seafhttp(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.10.102:8082;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout  36000s;
    proxy_read_timeout  36000s;
    proxy_send_timeout  36000s;
    send_timeout  36000s;
}

location ~ / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.10.101:8065;
}
```

But this again does work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://192.168.10.102:8000/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse  / http://192.168.10.102:8000/
```

+

```
location /seafhttp {
    rewrite ^/seafhttp(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.10.102:8082;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout  36000s;
    proxy_read_timeout  36000s;
    proxy_send_timeout  36000s;
    send_timeout  36000s;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix below:

```
location ^~ /seafhttp {
    rewrite ^/seafhttp(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.10.102:8082;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout  36000s;
    proxy_read_timeout  36000s;
    proxy_send_timeout  36000s;
    send_timeout  36000s;
}

location ~ / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.10.102:8000;
}
```